# Peut on installer dartPad sur sur son Pc Windows?

Tags: installation

je n'arrive pas a installer Dartpad sur mon PC

je veux un aide pour installer DartPad en local.
je veux apprendre a programme des applications avec Flutter mais je doit d'abord maitrise Dart Mais je veux l'utilise en local et non et ligne